# Dynamics CRM Integration - Multiple Tenants Possible via Single App Registration?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, dynamics-crm-365

We have a hosted application that needs access to customer data in their dynamics instance.

We have done this in the past with other CRMS such as HubSpot, Maximizer, and Zoho through OAuth 2.

A quick overview of what has worked for these CRMS:

1. We create an Application for our organization.
2. User goes to a redirect url that prompts with a username / password.
3. On the redirect url, we exchange code for a token
4. We are then able to create accounts for the logged in user's instance.

The error we are receiving with Dynamics 365:

AADSTS50020: User account 'foo@bar.com' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/{GUID}/' does not exist in tenant 'test' and cannot access the application '{GUID}'(Test Connect) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

This error does not happen if we use a user account from our own instance.

Are multiple tenants possible?

Answer (score 0):

Every user needs to be licensed in your tenant to access Dynamics.

I suggest you have a look at PowerApps Portals as a workaround.